# Шаурма или шаверма?

Tags: грамотная-речь, заимствования

Понимаю, вопрос глупый, но все-таки.
Мне всегда казалось, что правильно блюдо называть *"шаурма"*. Но в Питере принято писать — *"шаверма"*.
По идее, если это слово тюркского происхождения, то "шаверма" — неправильно, потому что в тюркских словах ударение всегда падает на последний слог, как во французском языке. Ударение же на предпоследний слог характерно, скорее, для арабского языка.

Скажите, пожалуйста, ***как*** все-таки правильно и литературно: **шаурма** или **шаверма**?

Comment: Друзья, слово шаурма и шаверма не тюркского происхождения. Оно из семитских групп языков: иврита, арабского. Ударение правильно ставить на второй слог. В случае с шавермой - это еврейское название блюда, ударение ставится на шавЕрма, от слова шварма. В случае арабского произношения, более сглаженный вариат шаУрма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словарная фиксация:  шаурм***а***. Петербургский вариант "шаверма" не соответствует литературной норме.

Answer (score 1):

В ***других*** городах России можно встретить и ***шаурму***, и ***шаверму*** ; а поскольку и готовят эти блюда по-разному, то иногда оба названия мирно уживаются друг с другом в одном городе, обозначая при этом разные виды "фастфуда".

Comment: Откуда информация?! На такие вещи надо все-таки ссылку давать. Если это ваше лично мнение, то готов поспорить насчет "разных видов".  Да, иногда менеджеры и маркетологи использует разные названия для продвижения продукта. Но в случае с шаурмой-шавермой это не очень правдоподобно.

Answer (score 1):

У этого слова нет одного языка-источника. В русский язык это слово пришло в разных формах, но наибольшее распространение получили две: шаурма и шаверма.
**В новейших академических словарях русского языка зафиксировано только шаурма**. Но *шаверма* еще не утратила шансы на «прописку» в академическом словаре. А петербуржцам рекомендуется продолжать говорить шаверма. Но при этом в строгих формах письменной речи все-таки нужно употреблять слово шаурма, рекомендуемое нормативными словарями.
Подробности в статье, опубликованной на сайте Грамота:
[7 вопросов о шаурме и шаверме](http://gramota.ru/lenta/news/8_3199)